# React App throwing a react router `useLocation()` error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I've Created a component which works in Storybook, it's been published to a private repo. When I consume this navigation component which uses `<navLink>` I get a `Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component`. I've searched for this and keep getting the same answer. Which is to warp the app in a `<BrowserRouter>` tag. However my app IS wrapped in a `<BrowserRouter>` tag and I still get this error. Any help would be welcome as I'm banging my head off the screen here.

### Index file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/Container/App';
import store from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') || new DocumentFragment());
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

### App file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PageLayout from '../UI/PageLayout/PageLayout';
import Home from '../Home/Home';
import Portal from '../Portal/Portal';
import ProductSearch from '../ProductSearch/ProductSearch';
import { InternalRoutes } from '../../common/enums/internal-routes';
import Inbox from '../Inbox/Inbox';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <PageLayout >
      <Routes>
        <Route path={InternalRoutes.Default} element={<Home />} />
        <Route path={InternalRoutes.Home} element={<Home />} />
        <Route path={InternalRoutes.Inbox} element={<Inbox />} />
        <Route path={InternalRoutes.Portal} element={<Portal />} />
        <Route path={InternalRoutes.ProductSearch} element={<ProductSearch />} />
      </Routes>             
    </PageLayout>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### PageLayout file

```js
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Logo, PrimaryNavigation } from 'my-component-lib';
import { InternalRoutes as Routes } from '../../../common/enums/internal-routes';

interface I_PageLayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const PageLayout:FC<I_PageLayoutProps> = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className="body_grid">
      <header>
        <Logo />
        <PrimaryNavigation navigationLinks={Object.values(Routes) as unknown as Array<keyof typeof Routes>} />
      </header>
      <div className={'main_Grid'} >{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageLayout;
```

Comment: Where is any `useLocation` hook being used? Please include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using. See [mcve].

Comment: It seems like you are importing this `PrimaryNavigation` from an external component library. The issue may be that you've built it using a separate instance of React. You can try listing `react` and `react-router-dom` as peer dependencies, or just move the `PrimaryNavigation` component into your app's repo.

Answer (score -2):

You can solve this problem by **removing** `<BrowserRouter>` from `Index` file and **wrapping** `<Routes>` tag in `App` file

**New Index**

```
   import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import App from './components/Container/App';
    import store from './app/store';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') || new DocumentFragment());
    root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Provider store={store}>
                    <App />
            </Provider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
```

**New App file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route,BrowserRouter  } from 'react-router-dom';
import PageLayout from '../UI/PageLayout/PageLayout';
import Home from '../Home/Home';
import Portal from '../Portal/Portal';
import ProductSearch from '../ProductSearch/ProductSearch';
import { InternalRoutes } from '../../common/enums/internal-routes';
import Inbox from '../Inbox/Inbox';

const App = () => {

    return (
        <PageLayout >
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={InternalRoutes.Default} element={<Home />} />
                <Route path={InternalRoutes.Home} element={<Home />} />
                <Route path={InternalRoutes.Inbox} element={<Inbox />} />
                <Route path={InternalRoutes.Portal} element={<Portal />} />
                <Route path={InternalRoutes.ProductSearch} element={<ProductSearch />} />
            </Routes> 
           </BrowserRouter>              
        </PageLayout>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I hope this will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look but this wouldn't work, the navigation component is inside <PageLayout> so the context would be outside React Router like this.